# How can I join two words in python?

Tags: python, file

```
user = input('Create a Username: ')
passw = input('Create a Password: ')
f = open("users.txt", "a")
combine = "|".join("\n" + user + passw)
f.write(combine)
f.close()
```

I created a variable where I can combine both of the username and password and write It in the users.txt file.but when I try to combine "admin" and "99" It goes like this:
`a|d|m|i|n|9|9|`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-string-literal

Comment: ``"|".join(["\n" ,user , passw])``, because string is a iterable & join is iterating over each  value in string

Comment: ```open("users.txt", "a").write(input('Create a Username: ') + '|' + input('Create a Password: '))```

Comment: strings are iterable, str.join(.., iterable) works on iterables. So it combined each character of the combined string `"\n" + user + passw` to each other and seperates by | ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do simple old concatenation:

```
user = input('Create a Username: ')
passw = input('Create a Password: ')
f = open("users.txt", "a")
combine = user + "|" + passw
f.write(combine)
f.close()
```